# Dynamically Adding Widgets in list item on button’s on pressed function in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart

i have list item on my screen ... All I want to know is, how to add dynamicaly a list item on pressing a floatingActionbutton....
here is a first screen on which i have a button (for adding one more item like above item) [image]

in this picture after selecting suit id .. i want when i pressed add button a copy of naap widget displays from which i can select 2ndsuit id...
i read a tutorial from medium.com but there he used sijmply two text boxes whixh is very easy..whereas in my situation it is pretty difficult for me.... but the situation is same .. you can also visit https://medium.com/@anilpandey071999/dynamically-adding-widgets-on-buttons-on-pressed-function-in-flutter-4d9f139744c7

following is my code...

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_auth/Screens/Dashboard/DashboardScreen.dart';
import 'package:flutter_auth/Screens/SearchCustomer/SearchCustomerScreen.dart';
import 'package:flutter_auth/components/NavDrawer.dart';
import 'package:flutter_auth/components/bottombar.dart';
import 'package:flutter_auth/components/rounded_button.dart';
import 'package:flutter_auth/components/rounded_input_field.dart';
import 'package:flutter_auth/components/drop_down_list.dart';
import 'package:flutter_auth/Screens/Welcome/welcome_screen.dart';
import '../../constants.dart';
import 'components/inputtextfieldname.dart';
import 'components/inputtextfieldnumber.dart';


class AddCustomerScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AddCustomerScreenState createState() => _AddCustomerScreenState();
}

class _AddCustomerScreenState extends State<AddCustomerScreen> {
  final CategoriesScroller categoriesScroller = CategoriesScroller();

  ScrollController controller = ScrollController();

  bool closeTopContainer = false;
  double topContainer = 0;

  List<Widget> itemsData = [];

  void getPostsData() {
    List<AddCustomerScreen> dynamicList = [];
    List<dynamic> responseList = Customer_Data;
    List<Widget> listItems = [];
    responseList.forEach((post) {
      listItems.add(GestureDetector(

        onTap: () {
        //  _navigateAndDisplaySelection(context);
        },

        child: Container(

            height: 200,
            margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 10),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20.0)), color: Colors.white, boxShadow: [
              BoxShadow(color: Colors.black.withAlpha(100), blurRadius: 10.0),
            ]),

            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0, vertical: 10),
              child: Column(

                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                children: <Widget>[
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                   Text(
                  post["name"],  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: const TextStyle( fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,color: kPrimaryColor),
                       ),

                 // Expanded(child: drop_down_list())

                ],

                 ),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Padding(
                    padding:EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal:10.0),
                    child:Container(
                      height:2.0,
                      width:275.0,
                      color:kPrimaryColor),),
                ],),
                  Row(
mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      IconButton(onPressed: (){}, icon: Icon(Icons.camera_alt_rounded), iconSize: 30,color: Color(0XFFc49864)),
                       IconButton(onPressed: (){}, icon: Icon(Icons.add_photo_alternate_outlined), iconSize: 30,color: Color(0XFFc49864))
                    ],
                  ),
                  Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Expanded(child: drop_down_list())

                      ])

          ],),


            )),));
    });
    setState(() {
      itemsData = listItems;

    });

  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getPostsData();
    controller.addListener(() {
      setState(() {
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    final double categoryHeight = size.height*0.30;
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Add Customer'),
          actions: <Widget>[
            IconButton(
                 icon: Icon(Icons.home,),
              onPressed: (){Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) {
                    return WelcomeScreen();
                  },
                ),
              );},
            )
            
          ]
        ),

        drawer: NavDrawer(),

        body:Container(
          height: size.height,
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[

              const SizedBox(
                height: 10,
              ),
              AnimatedOpacity(
                duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 200),
                opacity: closeTopContainer?0:1,
                child: AnimatedContainer(
                    duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 200),
                    width: size.width,
                    alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                    height: closeTopContainer?0:categoryHeight,
                    child: categoriesScroller),
              ),
              Expanded(
                  child: ListView.builder(
                      controller: controller,
                      itemCount: itemsData.length,
                      physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        return itemsData[index];
                      })),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: () {
            // Add your onPressed code here!
          },
          child: const Icon(Icons.add),
          backgroundColor: Color(0xFF6D4C41),
        ),
        floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerFloat,
      ),

    );

  }

}

void _navigateAndDisplaySelection(BuildContext context) async {
  // Navigator.push returns a Future that completes after calling
  // Navigator.pop on the Selection Screen.
  final result = await Navigator.push(
    context,
    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SearchCustomerScreen()),
  );
}
class CategoriesScroller extends StatelessWidget {
  const CategoriesScroller();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final double categoryHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.35 - 50;
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
     // scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      child: Container(
        margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 25, horizontal: 25),
        child: FittedBox(
          fit: BoxFit.fill,
          alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
          child: Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                width: 400,
                margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10, vertical: 10),
                height: categoryHeight,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Color(0XFFc49864), borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20.0)),boxShadow: [
                BoxShadow(color: Colors.black.withAlpha(100), blurRadius: 10.0),]),
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      RoundInputField(
                        hintText: "Customer Name",

                        onChanged: (value) {},
                      ),
                      RoundInputFieldNumber(
                        hintText: "Phone Number",
                          icon: Icons.phone,
                        onChanged: (value) {},
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),


            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
class bottombar extends StatelessWidget {
  const bottombar();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
        child: Row(
          children: [
            IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.menu), onPressed: () {}),
            Spacer(),
            IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.search), onPressed: () {}),
            IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.more_vert), onPressed: () {}),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton:
      FloatingActionButton(child: Icon(Icons.add), onPressed: () {}),
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there any error or log?

Comment: no, i dont know how to do it ...

Comment: What all widget you required inside naap widget?

Comment: Naap is a label ..
Camera icon ... on touchong camera icon camera will be ON.
Gallery icon ... on touching gallery icon it will go to gallery...
and a dropdown list..SUit ID

Answer (score 0):

The most straight forward way is imho:

- embed the widget to be added with `showWidgetA ? WidgetA() : Container();`
- in your button you toggle the value `onPressed: () => showWidgetA = !showWidgetA` (`showWidgetA` being `bool`)